# Is it possible to transform a periodic function to a linear one?

Tags: functions

The title might be slightly misleading.

Consider the following *periodic* function. This happens because the data on the X-axis is constricted to a certain interval.
[image: periodic]

What I want is for the function to continue like in the picture below. Instead of *turning around*, I want it to go forward, breaking the interval set in the X-axis, so basically applying some sort of transformation to X such that it will keep the data flowing instead of turning.
[image: linear]

I hope this makes sense. Can anyone highlight some ideas for this?

Comment: Have you looked at phase unwrapping algorithms?

Comment: The 1st graph does not represent a function

Comment: @SandeepThilakan: good point. However, the question remains.

Answer (score 2):

Let the periodic function be $f(x)$.  One way to approach this would be to set $$ g(s):=\int_0^s(f(x)-\inf f(x))\,\text dx $$

For example, consider $f(x)=\sin x$.  The infimum of $\sin$ is $-1$.  So we would have $$g(s)=\int_0^s(\sin(x)-(-1))\,\text dx=\left.x-\cos x\right|_0^s=s+1-\cos s$$

The result:

[image]